# Android Studio unable to find explicit activity class Library After Merge Manifest

Tags: android

I Have Application where use library [Pick Image](https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage). But When I use it like this :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        new TedPermission(getApplicationContext())
                .setPermissionListener(permissionGetFotoListener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n" +
                        "Please turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
    }
```

i got error :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.myapp.android/com.gun0912.tedpermission.TedPermissionActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

**update**

I used any Library.
This problem occurs when the added **tools: node = "replace"** on the manifest, but if it is removed, I get an error **manifest merge failed**

so how to fix it ?

Comment: That activity must be specified in manifest file as by the docs says. Third party library which will have the activity named which you seen in the error should be declared like normal activity.

Comment: still get error

Answer (score 0):

add the activity to androidManifest.xml

or maybe the image pick library required their own activity to the manifest

```
<Application
.....>
<activity
        android:name=".TedPermissionActivity"/>

</application>
```